Laravel Append 'lat' and 'lng' keys to associative array
I have a json column in MySQL table that contains data of this sample:
[
    [
        -79.4936969567481,
        37.3504643767627
    ],
    [
        -79.4936969567481,
        37.3504643767627
    ]
]

I have a function that I would like to append 'lat' => and 'lng' => keys before the first value and second value of the array members respectively. So far I have:
$polygons = Polygon::get();
    
foreach ($polygons as $polygon) {
    $coordinates = $polygon->coordinates;
    
    // Transform the coordinates
    $newCoordinates = array_map(function ($coordinate) {
        return [
            'lat' => $coordinate[0],
            'lng' => $coordinate[1],
        ];
    }, $coordinates);
    
    // Update the model's coordinates column
    $polygon->coordinates = $newCoordinates;
    $polygon->save();
}

However, its resulting in
[
    {
        "lat": -79.4936969567481,
        "lng": 37.3504643767627
    },
    {
        "lat": -79.4936789563065,
        "lng": 37.3504513771715
    }
]

What could I be doing wrong? The { should be replaced by [, } by ] and : by =>

associative array (string or out of order keys) dont exist in Json format or in JavaScript. If you want a string index, you need to use objects hence the { } .

Mysql will save it as json (the format you described). Nothing is wrong there. However, you can add a cast to your Polygon model so it returns a php array to you.
class Polygon extends Model
{
    protected function casts()
    {
        return [
            'coordinates' => 'array'
        ];
    }
}

